# for() loop not repeating - Extendscript After Effects

Tags: javascript, for-loop, append, extendscript, after-effects

My for-loop will not repeat. I'm a noob when it comes to loops, would appreciate any help.

I have a dropdown list where a user can select a number (1-10). On selection my script generates a number of text layers with slider effects applied (this part is working) an expression is then applied to an animator of the selected layer which likes keyframe values to the sliders of the generated control layers.

EDIT

I'm beginning to understand loops a little better the loop is repeating(thanks @CherryDT).
I came up with the following solution, my execution may leave a little to be desired and it does not return exactly what I need.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Here's my code as it stands (if dropdown selection was set to 3).

```
    startRangeExp.expression; 

    var key = [];
    var x = "if(numKeys > 2){\n" + 
            "if (time < key(2).time){\n" +
                "key1;\n" ;
    var y = [];
    var z = "}\n" + 
            "}else{\n" + 
            "key1;\n" + 
            "};\n" ;
    var expressionStart ='';
    var expressionSecondPart ='';
    var expressionThirdPart ='';
    var expressionEnd ='';
        for(var i = 1; i <=pal.grp.groupFive.keyDrop.selection.index; i++){

            key[i] = "key"+i+ "= thisComp.layer('" +myLayers[0].name+ '_key_'+i + "').effect('Slider Control')('Slider').value;\n";
        
            y[i] = "} else if (time < key("+i+").time){\n" +
                                "key"+i+";\n";
            
    expressionStart += key[i];
    expressionSecondPart  = x;
    expressionThirdPart += y[i];
    expressionEnd = z;

startRangeExp.expression = expressionStart + expressionSecondPart  + expressionThirdPart + expressionEnd;   
        }
```

Which returns this

```
key1= thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_1').effect('Slider Control')('Slider').value;
key2= thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_2').effect('Slider Control')('Slider').value;
key3= thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_3').effect('Slider Control')('Slider').value;
if(numKeys > 2){
  if (time < key(2).time){
    key1;
  } else if (time < key(1).time){
    key1;
  } else if (time < key(2).time){
    key2;
  } else if (time < key(3).time){
    key3;
  }
}else{
  key1;
};
```

Desired return looks like this

```
key1 = thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_1').effect('Slider Control')('Slider');
key2 = thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_1').effect('Slider Control')('Slider');
key3 = thisComp.layer('Text-Layer-Name_1_key_1').effect('Slider Control')('Slider');
if(numKeys > 2){ 
  if (time < key(2).time){
    key1;
  }else if (time < key(3).time){
    key2;
  }else{
    key3;
  }
}else{ 
  key1; 
};
```

Any suggestions on how I should approach editing my code to attain the desired result?

Cheers,
J

Comment: It is repeating but you don't keep the previous values anywhere... You store them in key[...] but you only ever use the last value that you put there. I guess you want `+=` instead of `=` in the last assignment... But then you have the y string also in every iteration so maybe append the y only _after_ the loop.

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT, that works and it's now repeating, along with y. This has corrected my course. Thank you!